# custom kernel for msm8909

Tags: android, kernel, android-5.0-lollipop, boot

Need help. I have a ZTE blade a460 phone with broken screen and i want to make it something usefull like a nfs server. I want a custom compiled kernel so, i extract the config from the original kernel using the extract-ikconfig script. I compile kernel using this config and the original dtbs from ramdisk but the kernel dont bootup. After much trials i think something special is needed. Knows someone what specific is needed for this machine? compiling Modules for the original kernel needs the extra flag -fno-pic. Is needed for the new kernel too? The phone has 3.10.49 kernel and android 5.1.1 Lollipop. I use arm-linux-androideabi-4.8 (the same as they use to compile the original kernel). Adb boot to boot the new image.

Comment: i used wrong toolchain.  With linaro 4.9.4 it boots right.

Comment: Also only the AIK-tools unpack and repack the ramdisk right.